# Chrome extension tutorial pop-up does not pop on Mac Snow Leopard?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have Chrome for Mac on my mini-mac running OS 1 10.6.8 and starting to learn how to write Chrome extensions.

Followed the sample tutorial for the browser-action pop-up.

Does NOT pop-up on my mini-mac, but the same code works just fine on my Macbook Pro running OS X 10.9.2

The only obvious difference is that my mini-mac cannot be upgraded to Mavericks, etc. nor to Java 7.x, however, there are other published extensions that I am able to load that work just fine on both Macs and both OS X.

I have not found any answers surfing -- any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome extensions do not depend on OS X Mavericks, and they do not require Java 7, and as you have mentioned, others are working well on your Mac Mini. (They run on my Mac Mini too.)

You can check to see if you have developer mode enabled by going to chrome://extensions and making sure the "Developer Mode" checkbox near the top of the page is enabled.

Another potential problem is if you are running a very old version of chrome, say older than about 6 months.

See if other tutorial apps work.  It might be good to start with this one:
https://developer.chrome.com/apps/first_app

Comment: Hmmm ... I have not been working on the extension for a few weeks.  I will check out the tutorial that you are suggesting and report back.  BTW Chrome is Version 34.0.1847.131 - up-to-date.  The extension works as the initializer gets fired and i put a pop-up that show.  By the toolbar button does not generate the pop-over dialog.